# Fancybox callbackOnShow not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am trying to call a function on the load of the fancybox dialog(content loaded as iFrame) but call to the "callbackOnShow" is not working. Appreciate any help on this.

here's the code snippet:

jQuery:

```
$("#link1").fancybox({
        'width': '50%',
        'height': '50%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'callbackOnShow': function () {            
                alert("Hello");            
        }
    });
```

HTML code which is shown in the fancybox:

```
<div>
    <div class="signup">            
        <div id="test">         
            <a id="Log" class="but" href="#"><strong>Sign in</strong> </a>          
    </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see the callbackOnShow @ http://fancybox.net/api ?
Which fancybox are you using ? can you add it to a fiddle ?

Fancybox provides onComplete option as it works fine when the show is completed.
Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/SrT4T/

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

- onStart
- onCancel
- onComplete
- onCleanup
- onClosed

I think what you're looking for is the onComplete function. onComplete will be called once the content is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the last version of fancybox (2.0.1). There, the callbacks are named differentely.

Actually, there isn't still `callbackOnShow` ;) and your post was written before the last release of fancybox...

But for guys looking around, then the callback `onComplete` was replaced by `afterShow`!